Movie from 80s or 90s: portal to another world with primitive men
I'm looking for a movie from the 90s or 80s, I think.
There was a portal between Earth and another world, and in that world there were like primitive men and a warrior was fighting an evil leader and his thugs.
There is a scene where they roll a huge rock over a group of men in a fight and crush them. People from earth go enter the portal with a car and the primitive men thought it was magic, and the evil leader comes to earth and goes to a clothes store and makes a mess.
Sorry if I am not clear enough but I used to watch it when I was a kid and I only have some flashbacks.

It may also be the near identical he man movie https://youtu.be/CF20B8p4F08

The second Beastmaster movie from 1991. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beastmaster_2:_Through_the_Portal_of_Time

Dar, the Beastmaster (Marc Singer), is back and now he has to deal with his half-brother, Arklon (Wings Hauser), and a sorceress named Lyranna (Sarah Douglas) who have escaped to present day Los Angeles. Despite the name, the movie is not about traveling through a time portal, but traveling through a portal to a parallel universe that 1991 Earth exists in. Dar and his animal companions, Ruh, Kodo, Podo and Sharak, must follow them through the portal and stop them from obtaining a neutron bomb. During his visit, Dar meets a rich girl named Jackie Trent (Kari Wuhrer) and they become friends.

The clothing store scene is in the trailer:



The car is featured on the poster as well.
https://www.cinematerial.com/media/posters/sm/ss/ss2pozlh.jpg?v=1456286932

oh my god this is it i was searching forever this site is awesome. sorry for my English
